# Not receiving emails for Hotmail Email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I am a hotmail/outlook user and use windows10.  Currently, I am having a problem receiving emails online and on my phone.  For instance, my sister recently sent one and I didn't receive it, yet when she forwarded it to my gmail, which is connected to my hotmail account, it was received.

I looked up what might be going on at this site: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/I-didn-t-receive-an-email-someone-sent-to-my-Oultook-com-account-d39e3341-8d79-4bf1-b3c7-ded602233642

I tried all solutions, but to no avail.  It doesn't appear to be a junk email problem, such as in other people's cases.

Recently, my sister got a message entitled: "Warning: Could not send message for past 4 hours." 
Pasted in the message was this

> <<< 421 RP-001 (SNT004-MC1F36) Unfortunately, some messages from
>   148.163.XXX.XXX weren't sent. Please try again. We have limits for how many messages can be sent per hour and per day. You can also refer to
>   http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. ... while
>   talking to mx1.hotmail.com.:
>
> Blockquote

Note: removed IP Address for privacy.

So my problem appears to be related to this: "421 RP-001" error, however I don't why this might be, because my home network works for others and everything  was fine yesterday.
How should I resolve this? Why might this be happening?

Comment: "Why might this be happening?" - Sounds like your sister's account is compromised and being used to send spam, based on the message she received, saying she was sending to many emails

Comment: Ah I suspected it didn't have to do with my email.  The only other email I didn't get came from this other person using a Stanford email address.  So it might be a problem with their server...